# Techniques for proving that a rational map is not regular at a given point

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Apologies in advance if this question is too vague, but I was wondering generally what techniques are available when one is trying to prove that a rational map between varieties is not regular at a given point.

For example, I'm looking at the projective variety $V \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ given by $Y^2 Z = X^3 + X^2 Z$, and the rational map $\phi: V \to \mathbb{P}^1$ given by $\phi([X:Y:Z]) = [Y:X]$.  To show that $\phi$ is not regular at $[0:0:1]$, one can argue by singularities: if it was regular there, the map $\phi$ would in fact be an isomorphism, which can't happen since $V$ has a singular point while $\mathbb{P}^1$ does not.

Another way I was thinking of trying to prove such a statement was by arguing that any representation $[f:g]$ of $\phi$ by homogeneous polynomials of the same degree must vanish identically at $[0:0:1]$; however this approach seems to be more ad hoc and harder to generalize.

So, I'm curious if anyone has insight into what one does in practice when trying to prove a given rational map is not regular at a point; is it usually some sort of singularity argument as above that comes up, or do you just have to play around with polynomial representations of the given map?  Thanks!

Comment: The second idea is what you're looking for. Since "$[Y:X] = [0:0]$" is not a valid point of $\mathbb P^1$, the map is not defined there, the end. Your first idea is actually more ad hoc since it relies on $\phi$ being degree $1$ and $V$ having a singular point. But one encounters finite maps of higher degree obtained by projecting from a smooth point all the time.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Why can we stop there?  Don't we have to show that for any representation of $[Y:X]$ as $[f:g]$ with $f$ and $g$ homogeneous of the same degree, we must have $f(P) = g(P) = 0$?

Comment: @TabesBridges There must be more to the argument than what you've written. Otherwise, why couldn't I say the same thing about the map $\pi: E \to \mathbb{P}^1$, $[X:Y:Z] \mapsto [X:Z]$, where $E: Y^2 Z = X^3 - X Z^2$? $\pi([0:1:0]) = [X:Z] = [0:0]$, but it is of course possible to show that $\pi([0:1:0]) = [1:0]$.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn OK, I see your point. I'm sure there is an easier way to think about the homogeneous polynomial approach, but whatever it actually is, it is not coming to mind. I just double checked the statement of the "curve-to-projective extension theorem" and had forgotten that it only works for non-singular points. OP, are you not familiar with this theorem? Or are you specifically looking to show this computationally in specific examples? Because it basically answers your question: you can always find a valid representation when the center of projection is a smooth point of the curve.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks.  Do you have a reference for this theorem? I'm not familiar with it but would be interested in learning about the extent to which it answers my question.

Comment: It's Theorem 16.5.1 in this version of Vakil's notes: http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf

Comment: @TabesBridges How does this result answer the question? The theorem gives a sufficient condition for a rational map to extend to a point $P$, namely that $P$ is smooth. But to answer the OP’s question, it seems that you’d need the converse of this result, which is false. Indeed, any constant morphism will extend to $P$ whether $P$ is smooth or not. Or for a less trivial example, the inclusion $V \setminus\{[0:0:1]\} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$ obviously extends to $[0:0:1]$ despite the fact that $[0:0:1]$ isn’t smooth.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn Again you are correct; I seem to have lost track of the question in the course of thinking about it last night. My apologies to all.